# create css file from scss / sass stream with json object stream using gulp in node

Tags: node.js, stream, sass, gulp

How to produce css output from a list of sass variables in form of json object in combination with a scss file that uses these variables?

actual flow will be:

`json / object representation of sass variables` + `.scss file` = `combined .css file`

Tried `json-sass`, but which produces Sass maps which can't be used instead of simple sass variables.

finally got `gulp-json-sass` which converts

```
{
  "someColor": "green",
  "someObject" : {
    "someKey" : "45px"
  }
}
```

to

```
$someColor: green;
$someObject-someKey: 45px;
```

Here the actual part comes, **how to use a user modified json object instead of a json file in the gulp process** `gulp.src(['some.json','some.scss'])`**?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes you have assigned your json string to a variable named `obj`

```
function streamifyText(text) {
    var s = new stream.Readable();
    s._read = function noop() {};
    s.push(text);
    s.push(null);
    return s;
}
```

The above function is used to convert a string to stream.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {

    var combinedStream = CombinedStream.create();
    combinedStream.append(streamifyText(JSON.stringify(obj)).pipe(vinylSourceStream('anyName.json')));
    combinedStream.append(fs.createReadStream('./some.scss').pipe(vinylSourceStream('anyName.scss')));

    combinedStream
        .pipe(vinylBuffer())
        .pipe(gulpJsonSass({sass: false}))
        .pipe(gulpConcat('combined.scss'))
        .pipe(gulpSass().on('error', gulpSass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('out/'));
});
```

More details about implementation is available here -

https://gist.github.com/midhunanew/338a4bb3adce51ab29387dbe5156718a